# Serializing & Deserialzing with PHP to add values

Tags: php, jquery

Here I have my code. Currently it shows the original, encodes the original and then decodes it; now somehow I need to be able to take my serialized Array and add another value to it!

Does anybody know how I could do this using PHP? Maybe with a Jquery example where I can type in another number and it would add that number to the array and serialize it?

Eventually that serialized data would be stored in a MySQL `row` until it is sent to the users' browser and then get deserialzed to use the data to locate items using those numbers, anyone have any ideas?

```
<?php
        $array["favoritesid1"] = "546";
        $array["favoritesid2"] = "516";
        $array["favoritesid3"] = "815";
        $array["favoritesid4"] = "234";
        $array["favoritesid5"] = "765";
        $str = serialize($array);


        echo "String Original:";
        print $str . "\n<br><br>";

        $strenc = urlencode($str);

        echo "String Original Encoded:";
        print $strenc . "\n<br><br>";

        $strunserialized = unserialize(urldecode($strenc));

        echo "String Original De-Encoded:";
        var_dump($strunserialized);



        ?>
```

Comment: unserialize, add your value, reserialize.

Comment: I'm not sure how i would do that @mkaatman Do you have any idea how i would?

Comment: Repeat the process, create your original serialisation. Then when you want to add something new to it, unserialise the string into an array, add new values and then reserialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quite simple, you just add an occurance to the array once you have unserialised it as the `unserialize()` recreates the serialized array, and then reserialise it if you want it that way.

```
<?php
$array["favoritesid1"] = "546";
$array["favoritesid2"] = "516";
$array["favoritesid3"] = "815";
$array["favoritesid4"] = "234";
$array["favoritesid5"] = "765";
$str = serialize($array);

echo "String Original:";
print $str . "\n<br><br>";

$strenc = urlencode($str);

echo "String Original Encoded:";
print $strenc . "\n<br><br>";

$strunserialized = unserialize(urldecode($strenc));

echo "String Original De-Encoded:";
var_dump($strunserialized);

echo 'Add another occurance';
$strunserialized["favoritesid6"] = "666";
print_r( $strunserialized );

echo 'Re Serialize the array';
$new_serial = serialize($strunserialized);
print $new_serial;
?>
```

Comment: To make it more fluent you could have it as a method that will serialize and unserialize

Comment: Yea, just trying to Keep It Simple.

Comment: This works and it is great! Just need to re encode it and it worked! Thanks a lot!